# Browser is not saving cookies

Tags: setcookie, httpcookie

I am calling API at *https://engine-beta.mydomain.com/list** inside **http://localhost.mydomain.com** website, API response with set-cookie: with domain **landing.vahanacloud.com**. The browser is ignoring(not saving) this cookie.

But with the same scenario, in API response with set-cookie: with domain **.maydomain.com** is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you host domain and you domain is different.

**Host Domain:** Where the api is deployed.
**App Domain:** Where you web app is running.

If you save cookie to parent domain, all the sub domain will have access to cookies but siblings domain will not have access to other sibling cookies.